# SoapClient failing to load WSDL, needs apache restart to work again

Tags: php, centos

Server is CENTOS with PHP 5.4 and Apache 2.2.

I have a SoapClient object like this:

```
$client = new \SoapClient(__DIR__ . "/wsdlfilehere.wsdl", array("soap_version"=>SOAP_1_2, "trace"=>true));
```

After awhile (within 24 hours), this code throws an error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '/wsdlfilehere.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "/wsdlfilehere.wsdl".

Then **after** I restart apache and it works again.

Edit:  even setting cache_wsdl to WSDL_CACHE_NONE doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around I finally found a workaround/solution.

Following this [link on Ubuntu's launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1160336) it seems that other people are also experiencing this problem.  I followed [zabuch's instruction at comment #6](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1160336/comments/6) and it seems to work now.  I agree with him that the issue might be on mod_php/php itself and not Ubuntu only, since I'm on CentOS and have experienced this problem.

From zabuch's comment:

> The workaround for the issue is to add this:
>
> libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
>
> before creating new SoapClient.

Comment: Does not help here (Windows, PHP 7.0.4)